# Change every line break except nth line break with regex on js

Tags: javascript, regex

I can't figure it out, how to change every nth line break to space.

I have this regex code to change all line breaks to spaces:

```
this.value.replace(/\n/g, ' ');
```

It changes it all, but it should change every line break except the 3rd one, for example:

- line1
- line2
- li3
- li4
- li5
- li6

These lines should be changed to:

- line1 line2 li3
- li4 li5 li6

What regex should I use to get these results?

Comment: I would create an array of lines and  then group and join the elements per your requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture each line into separate group and replace `\n` by `space` after 1st and 2nd group:

```
var re = /([^\n]*)\n([^\n]*)\n([^\n]*)(\n|$)/g; 
var str = 'line1\nline2\nli3\nli4\nli5\nli6';

var result = str.replace(re, '$1 $2 $3$4');
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vV8qY8/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.replace` callback function:

```
function replaceLineBreaks(text) {
   var index = 1;
   return text.replace(/\n/g, function(){  
      return index++ % 3 == 0 ? '\n' : ' ';  
   });
}

var replacedText = replaceLineBreaks(text);
```

**Demo:**

```js
var text = "line1\n\
  line2\n\
  line3\n\
  line4\n\
  line5\n\
  line6\n";

function replaceLineBreaks(text) {
   var index = 1;
   return text.replace(/\n/g, function() {
      return index++ % 3 == 0 ? '<br>' : ' '; //br for testing purposes
   });
}

document.body.innerHTML = replaceLineBreaks(text);
```